# vector initialization, getting an error using code from C++ book

Tags: c++, vector

The code `vector<int> v = {5, 7, 9, 4, 6, 8};` which is from a C++ book gives me the error, `Error: initialization with '{...}' is not allowed for object of type "Vector<int>"` What's going on? I'm using 'visual C++ 2010 express' on windows 8.1 if that matters.

Comment: You need a compiler that supports C++11 for that.

Comment: Namely, Visual Studio 2013 has that support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This type of initialization is supported only in C++11, which VS 2010 does not support. You can replace it with old-style initialization. Unfortunately, it would use an extra array, but at least you would be able to get past this point in building your project:

```
int vectorData[] = {5, 7, 9, 4, 6, 8};
vector<int> v(vectorData, vectorData+6);
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/Ar3ohP)

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio even now does not support all of C++11; VS2010 supported very little of it.

[Support for initialiser lists was added in VS2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx).

I strongly recommend bookmarking that MSDN page if you're going to be learning C++11 on Windows. Sadly, the real world still has some way to go before it catches up to the books.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, [initializer lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Initializer_lists) is a new feature of the C++11 standard. Vector initialization using initializer list therefore requires a compiler/platform that supports some C++11 features.

MSVC supports initailizer lists from C++11 since the Visual Studio 2013 version. See [for minimum Visual Studio version for different C++11 features](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

the list initialisation is introduced on C++11. Your compiler should be C++11 Compliant to compile your code. You had to use the VS 2012 or later to use list uniform initialisation successfully.